# Elm and Radio button wonkiness

Tags: elm

I've been creating a survey with elm that uses radio buttons for different questions. Users can click back and forth between questions and select different radio options. However, I get some wonky behavior if the user backtracks through the survey.

If you make some selections, click "next question" make a couple of selections and click "previous question" the previous selections you made "disappear"

I've created an example that you can view on [Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/mfKZ3Pt5Ba1/1).

Comment: I think you need to look into Html.Keyed to fix this sort of issue.  That or introduce some logic into the view that checks the model for the selected option.

Comment: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Keyed is the right. answer. You can see the same effect if you switch between the login and signup page here: http://rtfeldman.github.io/elm-spa-example-with-debug/#/login . Just add one keyed node at the root of each form/question.

Comment: I just went to that page and replicated the bug I'm experiencing. On the signup page, I filled in my email address and then clicked the sign in page. The password field was filled in. Likewise, I then filled in the password with 'mysecretpassword' and then went to the sign up page and lo & behold, it was there.

Comment: Is this a bug in Elm's VirtualDom after all?  Or at least a major compatibility problem?  The documentation of `Html.Keyed` states that it is an optimisation rather than a bug-fixing mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually fixed this by doing what Matthew Stevenson and Hal suggested in the comments of my question: use Elm's `Html.Keyed` library. I eventually ended up keying my table rows `tr` which seems to have fixed the problem.

Here is the [Updated Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/dVPkSWc98a1/0)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough.. this is a BootStrap issue. Try removing the reference to bootstrap, and try to replicate the bug. It goes away, I remember having the same issue with a previous project. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hm, removing bootstrap doesn't fix it for me. For instance, after removing Bootstrap, try selecting all "Frequently" for the first question, then all "Unsure" for the next question. If you navigate back, you should find all the "Frequently"'s have been reset.